# How can i get something to happen once per click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I hover over the button it changes color, but I also want to add a number to a list when I click on it. I got it to add the number but I want it to only happen once per click,

```
def button():
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if mouse[0] < 300 and mouse[1] < 300:
        topleft.color = (255, 0, 0)
        if click[0]:
            playerpattern.append(1)
    else:
        topleft.color = (100, 0, 0)

playerpattern = []

while playing:

    print(str(playerpattern))        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False

    button()
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

If the click is held down it just spams 1's. so if you click for 1 second too long it adds two 1's.

Comment: is there a `buttondown()` method? This seems sort of similar to fixing button bounce, maybe you could implement some sort of `click_last` variable and check `if (click[0] and not(click_last))`

Comment: @JakobLovern what would click_last = ?

Comment: The best way to get around this would be to check in the eventlog for the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event. Then trigger the update to `button()`. Example: `for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
 if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
  button()`

Comment: And there's the pygame version of `buttondown()`. Go with what @TheLazyScripter said, it's far less hackish than my idea.

Comment: sorry, been awhile. Forgot how to properly format comments!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter go ahead and post an answer. You've got *my* upvote.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter i dont know what you mean here : if even.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: button()              because one of the functionalities of button() is to highlight the button when the cursor is over it i dont know how they would work together. sorry if i'm not clear. I dont know how to format comments at all.

Comment: Basically, you only want to run your code when the click *happens*, not while the mouse is down. So you check every `event` in the event log (`pygame.event.get()`) to see if a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stab at @TheLazyScripter's code...

```py
def button_hover():
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if mouse[0] < 300 and mouse[1] < 300:
        topleft.color = (255, 0, 0)
    else:
        topleft.color = (100, 0, 0)

def clicky_button():
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if mouse[0] < 300 and mouse[1] < 300:
        playerpattern.append(1)

playerpattern = []

while playing:

    print(str(playerpattern))        

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicky_button()

    button_hover()
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

In essence, you check for multiple event types in your `for` loop. Keep your hover code isolated from your click code, as you can hover without clicking. When you hover, do the color changing. When you click, do the click code.

Comment: hey man thanks, i wont get a chance to try it until later but this seems solid!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is usually a `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` event.  If your problem is that a single click may be held too long, you can use a timer to ignore multiple `KEYDOWN` events that are shorter than, say, half a second. I think for fault tolerance, you may try both, listening for a `KEYUP` event as well as putting a timer on multiple `KEYDOWN` events.

Some example code I found on the PyGame site:

```py
def check_events(settings, screen, tile_map):
    """Watch for keyboard and mouse events"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(settings, event, screen, tile_map)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(settings, event, screen, tile_map)
```

Comment: Hi jkdev, thanks for the edits.  New to StackOverflow, so the formatting was off.  Looks better now. :-)